# Data of last 6 quarter including current quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get data of `last 6 quarter` in Oracle including current quarter. I mean if I run the query today so data between `01-JAN-2018` to `30-JUN-2019` should come in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    DUAL

WHERE
    DATE_FIELD >= (SYSDATE - (30*(3*6)))
```

What this query is doing is taking the current date (`SYSDATE`), and grabbing all values from the previous 6 quarters. The rationale is:
`30 = days in a month | 3 = months in a quarter | 6 = quarters specified by OP`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_months` and `trunc` functions for date value with `Q`(quarter) argument

```
select t.*
  from tab t
 where insert_date between
       trunc(add_months(sysdate,-3*5),'Q')
   and trunc(add_months(sysdate,3),'Q')-1;
```

<kbd>[Demo for verification](https://rextester.com/IAGR13523)</kbd>

> for the starting date, **-3*(6-1) = -3*5** considered, starting from **5** quarter back to be able to count **6** quarter including the current quarter. **3** is
>   obvious as being the number of **months** in each **quarter**.